# Caring for an outdoor loofah during the winter

Tags: plant-care

This is the first time I'm growing a loofah plant. I'm not sure what to do with it during the winter. It gets fairly cold where I'm at(frost in the mornings, no snow) and I have read that people bring their loofah plants inside. This isn't a possibility for me as I let it grow up a large tree.
How do I keep it from dying over the winter if it has to stay outside?
I thought about covering it as you can do with smaller trees but the vine has grown really high up the tree so this isn't a realistic possibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where I live it gets really cold so loofah is treated as an annual. Seeds sown in pots in April are ready to go out in late May and June. We aim for fast growth to try to have fruits before the frosts in October. Loofah here grows as a weak clambering vine that would hardy get off the ground without some kind of support or scaffolding such as a fence or trellis, and the vines can run to 10-18 feet long, which makes it real hard to think of bringing them in for the winter.

If your frosts are very light then you may get away with having the plant survive, but you might consider starting fresh from seed in your springtime since old annual plants, even if they can be given extended lives, are rarely as productive as young plants.